# Erro: undefined depois de uma requisição ajax dentro de outra

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, requisição

Segue o código:

```
$("#l_linha").change(function(){
    var linha = $(this).val();
    var dados = $("#l_linha").serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'buscarPonto.php',
            async: true,
            data: dados,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);

                for(i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
                var localizacao = new Array(response.length);

                localizacao[i] = L.latLng(response[i].lat, response[i].lng);

                console.log(localizacao[i]);

                $("#r_ponto").val(response[i].id);
                var ponto = new Array();
                ponto[i] = $("#r_ponto").serialize();
                var address = new Array();
                address[i]= response[i].address;
                var ultimo = new Array();
                var proximo = new Array();

                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'buscarHorario.php',
                async: true,
                data: ponto[i],
                success: function (response) {
                        console.log(localizacao[i]);
                    for(j = 0; j < response.length; j++){
                        ultimo[j] = response.ultimo;
                        proximo[j] = response.proximo;
                    }
                }
                });
                L.marker(localizacao[i], {icon: icone}).addTo(map).bindPopup(address[i] +'<br><span>Próximo horário:'+ ultimo[j] +'</span>').openPopup();
            }
        });
});
```

O problema é que a variável *ultimo[j]* fica undefined. E se eu passo a parte:

```
L.marker(localizacao[i], {icon: icone}).addTo(map).bindPopup(address[i] +'<br><span>Próximo horário:'+ ultimo[j] +'</span>').openPopup();
```

para dentro do *for(j = 0; j < response.length; j++)...* a variável localização fica undefined. Esse trecho de código tem o objetivo de fazer 2 requisições ajax uma para listar os pontos dos marcadores e outra para listar os horários específicos destes marcadores, a parte do back-end está ok só essa ai que não.

Comment: Utilize o `L.marker(localizacao[i]...` dentro de `complete: function (data) {     }` para garantir que a variável `ultimo` tenha um valor vindo do success.

Comment: success: function (response) {
                        console.log(localizacao[i]);
                    for(j = 0; j < response.length; j++){
                        ultimo[j] = response.ultimo;
                        proximo[j] = response.proximo;
                    }
                },
                complete: function(){
                  L.marker(localizacao[i], {icon: icone}).addTo(map).bindPopup(address[i] +'<br><span>Próximo horário:'+ ultimo[j] +'</span>').openPopup();  
                }     - - Aparece erro de syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, a segunda requisição ela vai ficar com dados `undefined` nesse código:

```
$("#l_linha").change(function(){
    var linha = $(this).val();
    var dados = $("#l_linha").serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'buscarPonto.php',
            async: true,
            data: dados,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);

                for(i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
                var localizacao = new Array(response.length);

                localizacao[i] = L.latLng(response[i].lat, response[i].lng);

                console.log(localizacao[i]);

                $("#r_ponto").val(response[i].id);
                var ponto = new Array();
                ponto[i] = $("#r_ponto").serialize();
                var address = new Array();
                address[i]= response[i].address;
                var ultimo = new Array();
                var proximo = new Array();

                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'buscarHorario.php',
                async: true,
                data: ponto[i],
                success: function (response) {
                        console.log(localizacao[i]);
                    for(j = 0; j < response.length; j++){
                        ultimo[j] = response.ultimo;
                        proximo[j] = response.proximo;
                    }
                }
                });
                L.marker(localizacao[i], {icon: icone}).addTo(map).bindPopup(address[i] +'<br><span>Próximo horário:'+ ultimo[j] +'</span>').openPopup();
            }
        });
});
```

Pois, o "sucess" é quando houver sucesso na requisição, então a segunda continua sem esperar a primeira, pois o `Ajax` é **assincrono*** e por ser assincrono ele acontece simultaneamente com outras requisições.

Para corrigir coloque dentro da clausula `complete`:

tente isso:

```
$("#l_linha").change(function(){
    var linha = $(this).val();
    var dados = $("#l_linha").serialize();

            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'buscarPonto.php',
            async: true,
            data: dados,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);

                for(i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
                var localizacao = new Array(response.length);

                localizacao[i] = L.latLng(response[i].lat, response[i].lng);

                console.log(localizacao[i]);

                $("#r_ponto").val(response[i].id);
                var ponto = new Array();
                ponto[i] = $("#r_ponto").serialize();
                var address = new Array();
                address[i]= response[i].address;
                var ultimo = new Array();
                var proximo = new Array();

            }
        }).done(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'buscarHorario.php',
                async: true,
                data: ponto[i],
                success: function (response) {
                        console.log(localizacao[i]);
                    for(j = 0; j < response.length; j++){
                        ultimo[j] = response.ultimo;
                        proximo[j] = response.proximo;
                    }
                }
                });
                L.marker(localizacao[i], {icon: icone}).addTo(map).bindPopup(address[i] +'<br><span>Próximo horário:'+ ultimo[j] +'</span>').openPopup();

        });;
});
```

Na documentação do [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) diz: 
"**complete** faz o callback, quando a requisição finaliza"

Comment: Não funcionou, o erro diz que $ajax(...).complete is not a funciton. Estou usando o jQuery 3.3.1

Comment: usa .done vou alterar na resposta. o complete seria tipo o succes: function, sabe?